# Extension for editing order in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal

Modifying Orders in the Back end of Magento:
Ie: If customer orders unstitched item, but then later on changes to stitched that also costs more, Or if customer orders wrong size, but then wants to change the size of ordered item, in the back end, we must be able to change the size, details of the product (custom stitched measurements) in the back end. Will it refund the extra money or if new order costs more how it will charge for new order amount.

Is there some extension that fullfill this need.
My Payment Methods are CC and Paypal.

Answer (score 2):

please check this extension completed your requirement.

1) https://www.iwdextensions.com/magento-edit-order-manager.html

2) http://amasty.com/better-order-management.html

Comment: They dont refund the payments